# Cropping maps (Raster source map and vector map as boundary)?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, masking, clip

I have DEM named "HD_DEM" (asc file) and vector map for lakes that named "Lakes". I want to crop lakes from HD_DEM. By following instructions of this link https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Cropping_maps ,I tried to crop.

```
v.to.rast in=Lakes@TEST out=Lakes_MASK3@TEST use=val value=1
```

and

```
r.mask vector=Lakes@TEST
```

the both gave me strange output. (Grey: Lakes, Yellows: output)
[image: mask_problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set your region to the lakes vector. Next, there's no need to convert to the vector mask layer to raster. Recent versions of r.mask can take a vector layer as input. But you need the -i option to create an "inverse" mask. So:

```
g.region -p vector=Lakes
r.mask -i vect=Lakes
r.mapcalc "HD_DWM_cropped = HD_DEM"
```